# How to get the status of the service inside docker using powershell

Tags: powershell, docker, dockerfile

I want to fetch the status of service inside docker container using powershell

```bsh
 $fetchService = docker exec -ti 33 powershell -c "get-service  servicename"

 If ($fetchService.Status -eq 'Running') {
 Write-Host "True"
 }
 Else{
 Write-Host $fetchService.Name
  Write-Host "False"
 }
```

Actual result is False but expected is true, also object fetch service is not avaliable in log.

Comment: $fetchService is a string, not an object. It will contain the output of the 'get-service  servicename' command so you will probably need to check if it contains 'Running' using a RegEx

Comment: @SourMonk Could you help me on syntax

Comment: There's a few ways you could go about it, this is a good article: https://powershellexplained.com/2017-07-31-Powershell-regex-regular-expression

Comment: @AdminOfThings : $fetchService is System.Object

Comment: Any other way to check the docker exec  container service status?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check what `$fetchService` ultimately contains. Whenever it's a string, an array of strings or something else. If it is a single string you could use `-like` or `-match` which support multiple options. One of them is a regular expression. It all depends on your input as to how it has to look.

Check [about_comparison_operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6) and [about_regular_expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-6). It should give you an idea.

Comment: Its returning object but i could not able to fetch value using Select-Object -Property Name

Comment: Well, did you inspect the object e.g. using `Get-Member`? What's the actual type of the object?